# Split long html table into two or more tables

Tags: css, pdf, html-table

I am generating pdf using pdfreactor, and I have one problem. The result that I am getting from my backend service is a very long HTML table, something like $this:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>01</th>
        <th>02</th>
        <th>03</th>
        <th>04</th>
        <th>05</th>
        <th>06</th>
        <th>07</th>
        <th>08</th>
        <th>09</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX (XXXX)</td>
        <td>XXXXXXX (XXXXXXX)</td>
        <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXX XXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXXXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12"><strong>XXXXXXXXX</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>XXXXXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXX XXX</td>
        <td>-XXXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>-XX X X</td>
        <td>-XXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXX</td>
        <td>-XXXXXXXX</td>
        <td>-X</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So, the client want's me to if the content is overflowing the page, split the table into two, or more tables.

If it was HTML document and not pdf, I could use Javascript to determine the width of the table element, and then split it, but I can't.

Is there any way some css master knows is this possible to do with css?

Comment: You can get the height of the `<tr>` and calculate, to check whether the row will exceed the total page height. If yes, close the table, add a page break and create a new table in a new page.

Comment: @user2450639 use `flexbox`

Comment: You think that flexbox is working with tables?